# How to use django ORM to an API JSON result and perform calculation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have thousands of attendance raw data (json) from a web tool that I extracted using their API.

How can I get them into a table format / python object so I can use Django query and do calculations.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDITED:

I have sample API data in json: (https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=9a917b8d12b4b55787cf0caaa9b929b8)

> {"cnt":3,"list":[{"coord":{"lon":37.62,"lat":55.75},"sys":{"type":1,"id":7323,"message":0.0036,"country":"RU","sunrise":1485753940,"sunset":1485784855},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"main":{"temp":-10.5,"pressure":1028,"humidity":66,"temp_min":-11,"temp_max":-10},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5,"deg":200},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1485793175,"id":524901,"name":"Moscow"},{"coord":{"lon":30.52,"lat":50.45},"sys":{"type":1,"id":7358,"message":0.0268,"country":"UA","sunrise":1485754480,"sunset":1485787716},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"main":{"temp":-11.04,"pressure":1033,"humidity":61,"temp_min":-15,"temp_max":-9},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3,"deg":150},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1485793175,"id":703448,"name":"Kiev"},{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0034,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762036,"sunset":1485794875},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"},{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"main":{"temp":7,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":5,"temp_max":8},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.6,"deg":90},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485793175,"id":2643743,"name":"London"}]}

Which I wanted to use in my django project and do query using django ORM. Below is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def home(request):
    response = requests.get('http://api.ipstack.com/check? 
                             access_key=c8fad3bad3b6ac4e7ee1a94fe486865b')
    data = response.json()

    return render(request, 'core/home.html',{'data':data})
```

- Is it efficient to import the data into my MS SQL database hence I can query 
  them using Django ORM.
- Or is there a better way to this?

(Hope I've put enough)

Comment: This is far too broad. You haven't said at all what you're doing, so how can we tell you a "better way"?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata